# Create New Site (multisite); can't get subdomain to work

Tags: multisite

I'm busy working on a website for myself, and within this (Wordpress) website I want to create a new (multisite) site. First I wanted to do everything according to several tutorials on the internet, but then it turned out to be already done by the theme I bought.

When I go to "Network Admin > Sites > Add New" there is obviously an option to add a new site. The only thing is is that it isn't a subdomain, it is just a new page/site after the slash (www.mysite.com/...). So:

[image: The option now]

When actually I just want newsubdomain.mysite.com.

I hope someone can help me with this! I can't get it to work, unfortunately.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem with Multisite setup. Check your wp-config.php file. Right under define('MULTISITE', true); you should have this:

define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);

If this is set to true you will be able to add new sites as subdomains. After you do this re-check in wp-admin, what extra lines you need to add to .htaccess and wp-config and you are ready to go.

Once you create a new subdomain website check if it works, if you get an error message don't worry, you probably just need to add A record for your domain that ponts to your subdomain.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. :) I added a subdomain, but I'm getting an error now; When I go to mynewsubdomain.mywebsite.com I'm getting only a line of text saying; "Apache is functioning normally". And when I'm going to mynewsubdomain.mywebsite.com/wp-admin I'm getting a full (404) Not Found error. :(

Comment: Ok let's try and fix this one :-), go to Network Admin / Network setup and check if you applied those exact changes to .htaccess and wp-config.php. I think there are some minor changes when you switch to subdomain option. After that check your domain DNS settings in order to make subdomain multisite work I neede to add a wildcard A record pointing to my server IP address. Note: if you change DNS records it will take some time to see if it fixes your problem, depending on TTL.

Comment: I applied the changes to the .htaccess and wp-config.php! I'm in the Domain DNS settings now; do I need to call it mynewsubdomain.mywebsite.com and then point it? Edit: no, that didn't work (my domain and hosting on are different parties). How do I add a new record correctly? I'm kinda new to this. I can send a screenshot if you want

Comment: Actually no. Try to add A record with name * that points to your server IP address. That way it is a wildcard that will detect all your subdomains. (If you go with your approach, Name: subdomain, you need to do this for every new site on the network).